# Linq to XML select distinct value from

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sharepoint-2010, linq-to-xml

I am working with sharePoint Lists webservice, in order to load a dropdown in search page I need to extract all the "ows_Country" name from XML, returend in XMLNode in the Format of :

```
<rs:data ItemCount="1" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset">
   <z:row ows_Title="Nike"    ows_ID="1" ows_Country="Spain"  xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" /> 
   <z:row ows_Title="Addidas" ows_ID="4" ows_Country="Brazil" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
   <z:row ows_Title="Puma"    ows_ID="5" ows_Country="Spain"  xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
</rs:data>
```

I need to use LINQ to get the distinct "ows_Country" from the XMLNode, Kindly help is probably my first experience with LINQ as well as XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XNamespace rs = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset";
XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);

var result = doc.Element(rs + "data")
                .Elements(z + "row")
                .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("ows_Country"))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dtb :) it really worked, I had been strugling from alomst 4 hours now.
I was trying with
           var countries = (from xml in doc.Descendants("z:row") select xml.Attribute("ows_Title").Value).Distinct();

and "z:row" was throwing some hexa value ":" error, I wasn't able to solve thanks a lot once again :) for timely help

Comment: dtd : "accept" an answer, is it some sort of link where I need to click ?? If it is "Was this post useful to you" then I have already opted yes there :)

Comment: dtd : Man what would you suggest as the best source to learn LINQ ??